# Why do I keep printing every set and how can I stop

Tags: java

I'm sorry if the title doesn't make sense. I want to print the last elements that comes out of maxSumarrayMid.

```
int maxsumarrayCross = maxSumarrayMid(arr,l,mid,r);
```

> this is where my function is called

```
private static int maxSumarrayMid(int[] arr, int l, int mid, int r) {   

    int leftSum = -1;
    int sum =0;
    int maxLeft = 0;
    int maxRight = 0;

    for(int i = mid;i >= l;i--){
        sum += arr[i];

        if (sum > leftSum)
            maxLeft = i;

        if (sum > leftSum)          
            leftSum = sum;

    }


    int rightSum = -1;
    sum = 0;

    for (int j = mid+1; j <= r; j++) {
        sum += arr[j];

        if (sum > rightSum)
            maxRight = j;

        if (sum > rightSum)
            rightSum = sum;

    }

    System.out.println("Arrive "+maxLeft);
    System.out.println("Depart: "+maxRight);
    return (leftSum+rightSum);

}



    return maximum(maxsumarrayLeft,maxsumarrayRight,maxsumarrayCross);
```

> This is where is returns. It can only return one number because it is used again.
>   This is what prints out. I only want the set in bold.

```
Arrive 0
Depart: 1
Arrive 0
Depart: 3
Arrive 1
Depart: 3
Arrive 4
Depart: 0
Arrive 0
Depart: 7
Arrive 4
Depart: 7
Arrive 1
Depart: 4
Arrive 0
Depart: 1
Arrive 0
Depart: 3
Arrive 1
Depart: 3
Arrive 4
Depart: 0
Arrive 0
Depart: 7
Arrive 4
Depart: 7
***Arrive 1
Depart: 4***
```

I would really appreciate any ideas. Maybe I'm just over thinking :/

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. I see no recursive calls in the code you posted.

Comment: The answer you probably want here would be to print only when the base case gets hit.  But, you do not have any explicit base case, and, as pointed out by @Eran you also are not making a recursive call.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean recursion. I was confused.